# Create a new column based on other columns

Tags: sql

I've managed to create the following column in a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE t_issue_dates as

SELECT issue_d,

cast(substr(issue_d,5,4) as numeric) as issue_year
FROM myDB
```

(The code recodes a year-month variable to a year-only variable)

However, i can't add this variable to my existing table "myDB". I've tried using the:

`ALTER TABLE myDB ADD v_year` - command, but i can't manage to get it right.

Does anyone have an idea how i add the above variable to the "original" table myDB?

Thank you!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I Cant see any Variable here, which RDBMS you are using. It is a column or a derived column, please tag with correct database

Comment: Please have a good read on how to add column to the existing table `Alter table TableName add columnname datatype`. You havent given datatype `int` to your statement after `v_year`

Comment: i'm new to coding so I'm not entirely sure what you mean with "RDBMS". However, i use the "DB Browser for SQLite". Doing the codes there and then copy them to jupiter notebook -python whenever they are working. Does this answer the question?

Comment: @CMHedborg it means are u using MSSQL server or MySql or Oracle. SQL is a generic word

Comment: Aight. Im still not entirely sure about the RDBMS. Whatsoever, i tried typing INT after my variable name. But how do i insert the above code (the one recoding year-month to year) into the now empty column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, many databases support computed or generated columns.  That means that you can add a virtual column to the database by doing:

```
alter table t_issue_dates add issue_year as (cast(substr(issue_d, 5, 4) as numeric));
```

I recommend this approach because `issue_year` is always up-to-date.

Second, you can do this as an actual column, but the value can get out-of-date and needs to be re-calculated for each inserted/updated row:

```
alter table t_issue_dates add issue_year numeric;

update t_issue_dates
    set issue_year = cast(substr(issue_d, 5, 4) as numeric);
```

For the record, I would use `int` rather than `numeric`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Gordon Linoff. When trying to run: **alter table t_issue_dates add issue_year as (cast(substr(issue_d, 5, 4) as numeric));** i get the following error:  **sqlite3.OperationalError) near "as": syntax error [SQL: u'alter table t_issue_dates add issue_year as (cast(substr(issue_d, 5, 4) as numeric));'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)** any idea?

Comment: I modified your code and now it seem to work. Thanks a million!!

Comment: @CMHedborg . . . In SQLite, you can use a view rather than a computed column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MSSQL. It would be worth of reading documentation or a simple google on `how to insert`

Adding column :

```
Alter table t_issue_dates 
 Add V_year Int
```

Next step: This will only insert data for this particular column.

```
Insert into t_issue_dates  (v_year)
SELECT 
cast(substr(issue_d,5,4) as numeric) 
FROM myDB
```

Comment: Much appreciated! The new column is created, however the "insert to..." doesn't seem to work. Columns are still empty, or actually "NULL"

Comment: it seems `issue_d` column values are null

Comment: @CMHedborg did u got any message when u have executed `insert into` query, ex; 100 rows affected ?

Comment: In my case i get values for all columns, but the one we created. I have to look into this later. Been trying for 3hrs, i think i need a break.

Comment: no error message, the query was executed successfully

Comment: @CMHedborg it should insert rows, it should also say how many rows are affected. whats your row count ?

Comment: 1041832 rows affected

Comment: You are using MySql i guess from the query above, are you able to say the datatype of issue_d column ?

Comment: I tried doing everything from the beginning. This time the column v_year was created and 520916 rows were added. In total there are 1041832 rows where the last 520916 rows shows a year for column v_year. However, the other columns just display NULL.

Comment: same issue, query executed but all NULL values